# Does Google cloud marketplace have any QA sandbox environment before pushing this app to production

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store, google-workspace

I am going to publish a Google app on G suite marketplace. This could be installed by any public org/individual end user install.

Does Google apps marketplace provide any QA sandbox environment before pushing this app to production?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to upload your app for Alpha/Beta testing, try following this documentation : [Set up alpha/beta tests](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en). You can also check [Beta test your app with users to get invaluable early feedback](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/beta-tests.html), it is included in the [Launch checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist.html):

> -**Upload your APK to the alpha or beta channel**
>
> - Alpha and beta testing can help greatly in discovering issues with your app, giving you the opportunity to fix those issues and raise the quality of your initial release. Learn how to [upload an APK](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469) and (if necessary) [expansion files](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797). Learn about [best practices for beta tests](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/beta-tests.html).

Use the Google Play Console to release early versions of your app to trusted users for alpha and beta testing, and get feedback to make improvements before full release.

Hope this helps.